# WordPress - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: wordpress

I encountered this error after I changed the Site URL and the WordPress URL. After that, I can't log in to the wp-admin. I can't access any of the pages.

Please help. How do I fix this since I have no access to the FTP and the dashboard? How do I redirect the page back to where it once was?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the hosting account? Are you using a shared hosting plan? If so, log in to your cPanel and from there go to phpMyAdmin. Then access your database and find the table named yourprefix_options (usually wp_options). Once you're in that table change the value of `site_url` and `home`for the correct site url.

Comment: Yes, You need atleast DB access to do that, these 2 parameters will bring back your site again